# Is there a way for me to increase the OD size of a barrel connector without having to replace it?

Tags: battery-charging

Is there a way to increase the OD size of a barrel connect without having to replace it.  Through use it has compressed the female receiver and now works either intermittently or falls out.

Comment: The device side of the connector usually has a spring that presses against the barrel.  Try using a pointed object (small screwdriver or something) to bend the spring so that it is closer to the center pin.  Or replace the socket in the device.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be to slip one or more tight fitting phosphor-bronze split sleeves over the plug but at some point the housing will prevent the larger diameter. However it is very unlikely that you would have such a sleeve in your junk box.  You could carefully cut a strip of [brass shim stock](https://www.google.com/search?q=brass%20shim%20stock&tbm=isch&sa=X) to a width the length of the exposed metal barrel part of the plug and a few centimetres long.  Carefully and tightly wrapping this over the shank of a Philips or Torx screw driver shank (that has a drive end smaller than the shank) of lesser diameter than the plug.  Then remove the coil and with great care you cut a turn off after size testing on the plug. If the added thickness is enough you are ready or you may need to add more than one layer.  Be careful that the sleeve does not get stuck into the socket, a very small amount of cyano-acrylate glue could be used to stick it in place, let it wick into the open gaps and set without any movement so the metal to metal contact is undisturbed.

Perhaps the lateral thinkers on SE.lifehacks might have some ideas.

The loosening socket problem is exacerbated when an oversized plug is forced into a socket also the centre pin is very often smaller on a larger plug so there will be poor contact there if this is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the plug, but with the socket on the device that the plug goes into.  A properly made socket should not wear out due to having a barrel in it for extended periods of time.  That means your socket is defective, or was a piece of crap to begin with.  The latter is quite possible on cheap high-volume consumer devices where the consumers buy only on price.

Before you replace the socket in the device, you can try what JRE suggested in a comment, which is to attempt to bend the wiper more towards the center so that it makes better contact with the barrel.  However, this is probably hard to do, and if it works it only indicates the wrong material was used for the wiper in the first place.

Another thing to try is cleaning the wiper.  Perhaps the problem isn't lack of spring action, but accumulated dirt.  Try getting in there with a cotton swab with some isopropyl alcohol on it.  Of course make sure the plug is clean too.

If none of the above work, then replace the socket.  These things usually have fairly similar footprints across manufacturers.  Once you figure out what the inner and outer diameters are, you should be able to buy one on Mouser or the like.  It would help to have the removed one in your hand to compare with pictures.  You may have to do some bending and/or filing on the new one, but it shouldn't be too hard to replace with something off the shelf from CUI or any of the other usual suspects.